# Where to Put Heavy Computing Functions in Electron

Tags: electron

I hope you are doing well! I am relatively new to Electron and after reading numerous articles, I am still confused on where I should put heavy computing functions in Electron. I plan on using node libraries in these functions and I have read numerous articles that state that these functions should be put in the main process. However, isn't there a chance that this would possibly overhead my main process and thus, block my renderers? This is definitely not desired and I was wondering why could I not just put these functions in preload.js. Wouldn't it be better for performance? Also, if I am only going to require node modules and only connect to my API, would there still be security concerns if I were to put these functions in the preload.js? Sorry for the basic questions and please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Mind that `preload.js` also runs in the renderer process, so this would definitely block your renderers. Are you familiar with [Electron's IPC concept](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Wouldn't this only block that specific renderer not all of the renderers? Let's say I have an invisible window where I have my heavy computing functions in a `preloadA.js` of that `windowA`. And I have a `windowB` that is visible and has a `preloadB`. If my heavy computing functions wear to overhead in `preloadA`, wouldn't it only affect `windowA`, not `windowB`? Whereas if I had all the functions be in `Main.js` and it overheads, it would affect every window. Could you please tell me if I am wrong? And if I am, would you suggest to put all the functions in the `Main.js`?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I am also using this as a reference if it helps, https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-run-background-worker-processes-in-an-electron-app-e0dc310a93cc. Thanks!

Comment: Now, using hidden renderers is a possibility but given how much resources Chromium uses per renderer (even if it's not rendering anything) may not be the route to go if you have a very diverse group of target machines. First though, it may be worthwile to define what you mean by "blocking". If you're doing everything synchronously, you'll definitely block everything if you do the heavy work in the main process. Asychronicity could help. However, such questions are hard to answer if you don't have a specific use case and problem, i.e. it's better to try it out first (and optimise later).

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Unfortunately they are synchronous. If I were to use hidden renderers, would it be bad practice to use node modules in the preload.js? As it seems Electron is currently encouraging people to not use node modules in the preload.js with sandbox mode being enabled by default starting from Electron 20. This is the reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web workers created in your renderer thread. They won't block.

However you mentioned planning to use node modules. So depending on what they are, it could make more sense to run them from the main process. (But see also https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/multithreading which points out that you can set `nodeIntegrationInWorker`, independently of `nodeIntegration`)

You can use https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html in Node too, or for a process-level separation there is also https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html.

Note that worker threads in the browser (and therefore the renderer thread) cannot share memory. Instead you have to serialize it to pass it back and forth. If your heavy compute process is working on large data structures, bear this in mind. I notice that *node* worker threads say they do allow sharing memory between threads.